# What are the state-of-the-art meta-reinforcement learning methods?

Tags: reinforcement-learning, meta-learning

This question can seem a little bit too broad, but I am wondering what are the current state-of-the-art works on meta reinforcement learning. Can you provide me with the current state-of-the-art in this field?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

One of the most recent papers on meta-RL is [meta-Q-learning](https://arxiv.org/pdf/1910.00125.pdf). This paper introduces Meta-Q-Learning (MQL), a new off-policy algorithm for meta-reinforcement learning (meta-RL). MQL builds upon three simple ideas.

- Q-learning is competitive with state-of-the-art meta-RL algorithms if given access to a context variable that is a representation of the past trajectory.
- Using a multi-task objective to maximize the average reward across the training tasks is an effective method to meta-train RL policies.
- past data from the meta-training replay buffer can be recycled to adapt the policy on a new task using off-policy updates

Experiments on standard continuous-control benchmarks suggest that MQL compares favorably with state-of-the-art meta-RL algorithms.

I think that other references to other work on meta-RL are present in the experiments part of the MQL paper.

Answer (score 1):

Meta-Reinforcement Learning can refer to a broad range of ideas. Also, different algorithms are SOTA under different evaluation metrics (sample efficiency, agent performance, adaptation speed on a new task, etc)

Assuming that you are referring to the problem of quickly learning/adapting to a new task by training an agent on a distribution of related tasks, the following are some popular algorithms

- PEARL [Rakelly et al., 2019]
- VariBAD [Zintgraf et al., 2020]
- Meta-Q-Learning [Fakoor et al., 2020]

**References:**

1. K Rakelly, A Xhou, D Quillen, C Finn, S Levine - [Efficient Off-Policy Meta-Reinforcement Learning via Probabilistic Context Variables](https://arxiv.org/abs/1903.08254), ICML 2019.
2. L Zintgraf et al., - [VariBAD: A Very Good Method for Bayes-Adaptive Deep RL via Meta-Learning](https://arxiv.org/abs/1910.08348), ICLR 2020.
3. R Fakoor, P Chaudhari, S Soatto, A J Smola - [Meta-Q-Learning](https://arxiv.org/abs/1910.00125), ICLR 2020.